# repeating animate code with jquery in better way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make simple animation that 
line length changing repeatedly.

and, here is my code

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var redline = $('.redline');
        setInterval(redmove,100)
    })
    function redmove(){
        var redline = $('.redline');
        redline.animate({'width':'500px'},2000)
        .animate({'width':'20px'},2000)
    }
```

```css
    .redline{
    background: red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="redline"></div>
```

my code runs well with no problem, but, I think there must be a better code(maybe more efficient..etc)

**So, here is the question**

1.If this code is not good, why?
(in perspective of something like efficiency...etc)

2.I want to know better code in this situation.

thanks!
HAPPY NEW YEAR!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't use CSS animation instead? That is easier.

Comment: @ata to be honest, I don't know how to make 'automatically repeating' animation with CSS...can you tell me how to?

Comment: There you go @Hannibal https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp
I agree with @ ata. Also jQuery animate is very slow and greedy performance-wise. If you want to work on simple animations go with CSS animations. If you want more complex stuffs go for a Javascript animation library. And don't forget about optimizations

Answer (score 1):

Look into this

```css
@keyframes changeWidth {
        0% {
            width: 20px;
        }
        50% {
            width: 500px;
        }
        100% {
            width: 20px;
        }
    }
    
 .redline {
     height: 50px;
     background-color:red;
     animation: 4s ease-out 0s infinite changeWidth;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="redline"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by CSS like below:

```css
.redline {
  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation-name: test_animation; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: test_animation;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes test_animation {
  0% {
    width: 20px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 500px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 20px;
  }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes test_animation {
  0% {
    width: 20px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 500px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="redline"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple CSS @keyframe animation , like so:

```css
.redline {
 background: red;
 height: 10px;
 width: 20px;
 animation-name: animateLine;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-fill-mode: ease-in;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes animateLine {
 0% {
  width: 20px;
 }
 50% {
  width: 500px;
 }
 100% {
  width: 20px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="redline"></div>
```

NOTE::- you can use [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to prefix you CSS and also you can reduce your css code by using the [animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) shorthand.